# MongoDB group by on two fields user and monthly count

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a table with fields createdBy(user name) and createdAt(date). Here I want to get the monthly count of records created by each user.

```
[
    { $group: {   
            _id: {$substr: ['$createdAt', 0, 7]},
            count: { $sum: 1 },
        }
    },
    { $project: { _id: 1, count: 1 } }, 
    { $sort: { _id: -1 } }, 
    { $limit: 15 }
]
```

Is there a way to get the data with single query or I need to fetch users first and then get the monthly count?

Thanks

Comment: Just extend `"_id"` in `"$group"` with `"createdBy"`.

Comment: something like https://mongoplayground.net/p/7uNg4hzaMdD for a starter?

Comment: If you can, change `createdAt` to be a real MongoDB datetime instead of a string.